# How to create table on heroku psql?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I am trying to setup a simple web application with postgres. After I have the application running (no database related code yet).

- I added a postgres db addon to app with the command `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev --app <app_name>`
- Ran heroku psql `heroku pg:psql --app`.
- Attempted to create a table from the prompt: `CREATE TABLE example_table ( a INTEGER );`
- I see the error:

  `ERROR:  no schema has been selected to create in`
  `LINE 1: CREATE TABLE example_table ( a INTEGER );`

Skimming the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connection-permissions), it looks like users have the permission to `CREATE`. I am not sure what `no schema` means for postgreSQL.

Note: I also ran the command `DROP OWNED BY current_user CASCADE;` (successfully) - it was on top of a setup .sql script to clean, create tables and constraints and add sample data. Unsure if that can affect anything here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the command `DROP OWNED BY current_user CASCADE;`, I reset the database and everything is working as expected. Re-ran the `DROP OWNED BY current_user CASCADE;` and the problem re-appeared.

Answer would be to avoid that command. Use Heroku reset command instead :

`heroku pg:reset --app <app_name>`

Answer (score 1):

https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/106067/30035

also try first to:

```
set search_path to "$user", public;
```

and if it does not help - try granting privs as from link above